# Count all Users

Tags: strapi

I have a simple question:
from ": 1337/users/count" I get the answer "404" although I have activated the authorization for "count" in "Roles & Premissions". Can someone give me a hint?
Please see screenshots!
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey you should not have a problem.
Check you don't have a typo in your address "http://localhost:1337/users/count" (if running locally)

Comment: if problems persist you can share your routes.json and controller. Although if you've made no changes to them they should not be relevant.

Comment: Have you tested in Potman?